# ZF2 Adding filters with element definition

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element

I am trying to add filters and validators with element definition. But so far it is not working. Here is my controller class code.

```
   public function validateAction() {
    $testVals =  Array ('question1' => 'value1' );


    $formMaker = $this->getServiceLocator ()->get ( 'ttForm\Maker' );

    $form = $formMaker->generateForm();

    $form->setData($testVals);

    if ($form->isValid()){
        echo "Valid form";
    }
    else{
        print_r($form->getMessages());
        echo "Invalid form";
    }
     die;

}
```

This is form class code

```
public function generateForm (){
    $element =    array (
         'options' => array(
             'label' => "First Name :",
         ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required',
    'type' => 'text'

        ),

        'name' => 'firstName',


        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
        ),


        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'not_empty',
            )),
    );
 $form = new Form();
 $form->add($element);
return $form;
```

}

As you can see in form class, I have attached filters and validators with element definition, it does not work. Looking at docs, it seems like we can do so. Can anybody point out missing link? Thanks.

Comment: in the method `generateForm` it seems that `$form` is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line while copying. I just updated now.

Comment: You can't add filters and validators directly in the form element spec, they're added to the input filter spec. Take a look at the docs, in particular the creation via factory example here -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#creation-via-factoryn If you scroll down the example specification you will see a note indicating it's possible to add input filter spec for your elements in the `input_filter` key.

Comment: Thank you Crisp. It did help.